# How to use react state in querySelector

Tags: reactjs

Instead of doing this:
`document.querySelector(".class1").addEventListener('wheel', this.doSomething)`

I want to do something like this:
`document.querySelector(this.state.currentClass).addEventListener('wheel', this.doSomething)`

Is it possible? The other workaround I can think of is like this:

```
let temp = "." + this.state.currentClass;
document.querySelector(temp).addEventListener('wheel', this.doSomething);
```

Is there a standard or more optimal way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use string interpolation and just do:

```
document.querySelector(`.${this.state.currentClass}`)
```

string interpolation works like this:

anything in the string is interpreted as a string EXCEPT anything in `${}` is read as javascript and converted to a string

`const hello = 'goodbye'`
e.g. `hello{hello}` // returns `hellogoodbye`

I would recommend doing it the way I've shown and anytime you want to append something, just update the className in `state`

Comment: What if I have to append something to it? Actually my className is numerical so I need to append a string to it. Like from `0` I want to make it `.0class` for `querySelector()`

Comment: @AkhileshSingla I have updated, let me know if you still need help